# VBA error handling not working when function being called generates error

Tags: excel, vba

I am iterating through rows,and looking up the first column of each row(name) using a different function for finding his marks.

For each "name" there is a particular entry in a different table("marks") which can also be blank or "-"

```
Sub main()
On error goto errorhandler
Dim name as string
Dim marks as double
Dim source as range
Dim runs as integer

runs = 1
Set source = Sheets("input").Range("$A$2")
i=1

Do until source.offset(i,0) = ""        'iterate through rows 

    name = source.offset(i,0)
    marks = find(name)

    do until runs * marks > 100
        runs = runs + 1 'since marks is not defined;runs overflows 
    Loop
    'a lot of code which relies on marks
errorhandler:
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub

Function find(name as string) as double
    find = application.vlookup(name,Sheets("values").Range("$A$2,$C$5"),2,0)
End function
```

now as i said the value in column 2 of that table can also be blank or "-" and thus results in error Runtime error 13 "Type mismatch"

i even tried putting on error statement inside the loop
VBA should normally search for error handling in the calling function i.e "main" but its not doing so

Comment: @Siddharth sorry, I miss read it, it was an edit by the OP, removing my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `Err.Clear` after `errorhandler:`

Also, see the Excel help on `Err.Clear` which reccomends `On Error Resume Next`
together with `If Err.Number <> 0 Then`

This will produce much clearer code

Something like

```
Sub main()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim name As String
    Dim marks As Double
    Dim source As Range

    Set source = Sheets("input").Range("$A$2")
    i = 1

    Do Until source.Offset(i, 0) = ""       'iterate through rows
        name = source.Offset(i, 0)
        marks = Find(name)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
        Else
            ' Your other code for non-error case here

        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually i dont want to use resume next because there is a lot of code between errorhandler and find function and will produce overflow if allowed to run.That is why i straight away want to skip to the next iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much your recommendations,worked like a charm;and just for curiosity why didnt it work with "on error goto errorhandler" ??

Comment: Because you did not have a `Err.Clear` to reset the error handling

Comment: but where will Err.clear come in my original code because i tried putting it below errorhandler: but it didnt work

Comment: @Chis neilsen: With respect, That is an incorrect way to handle errors.

Comment: it gets a bit tricky: to make that construct work you would need            `errorhandler: If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Resume errorhandler
            End If`

Comment: @Siddharth are you refering to my answer or the discussion around the OP?

Comment: @Chis neilsen: I am referring to the solution that you have given

Comment: @Chris, Thanx my original code is now working as well,but just for some more curiosity ;) why should i clear err;i mean my 1st iteration generates a runtime error it is handled,my second iteration also generates the same runtime error,so it should be handled as well shoudn't it ???or does Err corresponds to something else??

Comment: @Siddharth no offence taken or intended, but saying it is 'incorrect' is a bit strong.  It achieves what the OP wanted, and while its probably not how I would approach the problem, whether its fit for purpose really depends on the intended use of the code. (of course the unspecified 'other code' will have to handle its errors in its own way)

Comment: @Chis neilsen: if you put OERN right at the top then it will suppress all errors. For example if you don't have a Sheet("Input") then OERN will simply suppress the error instead of highlighting it. If I go by your method then I will use OERN inside the loop just before `marks = Find(name)` :)

Comment: @Kartik it really comes down to the fact that imbedding a error handler inside a loop is a poor design and difficult to manage.  I suggest you carefully read the excel vba help and google vba error handling (a good resource is [cpearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) )

Comment: @chris neilsen: I disagree with the point that "imbedding a error handler inside a loop is a poor design" i.e if you are referring to OERN. There are many scenarios where you have to use OERN inside a loop.

Comment: @chris, thanks for your help,i would surely look into it,actally i am an electrical engg student and working on a tool for my internship so not really good with VBA error handling (the code in the original post is just another way of putting what i am trying to achieve :) )

Answer (score 2):

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Sub main()
    On Error GoTo errorhandler

    Dim name As String
    Dim marks As Double
    Dim source As Range

    Set source = Sheets("input").Range("$A$2")
    i = 1

    Do Until source.Offset(i, 0) = ""       'iterate through rows
        name = source.Offset(i, 0)
        marks = find(name)
        Debug.Print marks
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Exit Sub
errorhandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub

Function find(name As String) As Double
    find = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, Sheets("values").Range("$A$2:$C$5"), 2, False)
End Function
```

EDIT: Kartik, Sorry, I didn't see that you have already accepted the answer.

**FOLLOWUP**

> > > actually i dont want to print any error message instead straightaway skip to the next iteration – Kartik Anand 14 secs ago

In that case you are handling error in the wrong section ;)

Try this

```
Sub main()
    Dim name As String
    Dim marks As Double
    Dim source As Range

    Set source = Sheets("input").Range("$A$2")
    i = 1

    Do Until source.Offset(i, 0) = ""       'iterate through rows
        name = source.Offset(i, 0)
        marks = find(name)
        Debug.Print marks
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Function find(name As String) As Double
    On Error GoTo earlyexit

    find = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, Sheets("values").Range("$A$2:$C$5"), 2, False)

    Exit Function
earlyexit:
    find = 0
End Function
```

Comment: actually i dont want to print any error message instead straightaway skip to the next iteration

Comment: but vba says if it encounters an error in a function it will check for error handling in the calling sub.so shoudnt it pass to main???and moreover putting it in the function wont allow me to skip a certain percentage of my code which will produce an error in main

Comment: your code isnt working as i said,it doesnt skip "the lines of code it should have" and thus produces an overflow error(which vba doesnt handle)

Comment: @Kartik Anand: I have updated the code now. Please check if you still get the errors.

Comment: sorry but i cant upload anything from my office computer!!i'll surely reply with the snapshots when i get back home;

Comment: wait for my edit in the original post;i'll show you where your code goes wrong

Comment: your amended code making find = 0 will actually cause me more harm as runs would now definitely overflow;this piece of code is the reason i want to skip some portions

Comment: @Kartik Anand: If Find = 0 (i.e marks=0) in case of an error, then `do until runs * marks > 100` will never execute for that entry so how will it harm you?

Comment: but then it is the same as either comparing find or comparing Err.number as suggested by chris isnt it??

Comment: Chris's solution is also correct :) Just ensure that you don't put OERN right at the top. That is incorrect way to an trap error :)